# How can I rotate text in Shutter?

Tags: shutter

Is there any way to rotate text in [Shutter Screenshot Tool](http://shutter-project.org/)?

**Example of the interface:**

[image: Shutter Interface]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is no way to rotate texts in Shutter. There was a bug report requesting this feature on launchpad. [See here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/shutter/+bug/1318096). You can visit the bug report and click on **This bug affects me** link (I too clicked on that link btw).

However, You can easily create a vertical text line using GIMP. To do so, after completing your edits with shutter. Use **Menu** -> **Screenshot** -> **Open with** to directly open the file in Gimp.

From GIMP's toolbox, add text (don't forget to set matching color with arrow if you like) and then using *Menu* -> *Layer* -> *Transform* rotate it. Then move the text object at your desired location on the picture.

Use *Menu* -> *File* -> *Overwrite* to save it. You'll have the edited screenshot with rotated text in shutter.

Comment: Thank you for the reference to the bug report! Do you happen to know if Shutter is still being developed?

Comment: It seems shutter development is currently not very active. The last version released was around 2014. So...

Comment: What a pity. Shutter is an excellent piece of software. If you have any ideas how to revive the project, then please do let me know.